# How to do the nodejs server Load test

Tags: node.js

We have created Chat application using Nodejs. I want to check Load test on Nodejs

Which module will be help to do the Load test of nodejs.

Comment: you tried anything?

Comment: I have just installed the artillery module for this. I need to check how i can write the test scripts . But i want to know which tool will be the good to use. Because I want to test mainly connecting nodejs via socket.io and push the message to other user.

Comment: I tested with Apache Jmeter and it was awesome for creating lot of load and clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally i use ab command for a simple testing

something like

```
ab -n 10000 -c 10000 http://www.example.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have used Socket.io and nodejs, Jmeter is one of best option -

Using Jmeter along with websocket plugin - https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter

Jmeter is a proven tool for web applications. Many concurrent users can be simulated for chat app.

Comment: Web application will connect nodejs via socket.io and push messages to users. Mainly using for chat application. I am new to Jmeter Any sample script for this

Comment: Check the post mentioned in answer, there entire procedure and demo is there

Comment: Hi I have followed the steps that are givien in the Link but i am getting below error                                                                                  
   [Execution Flow]
 - Opening new connection
 - Using response message pattern ""
 - Using disconnect pattern ""
 - Waiting for the server connection for 5000 MILLISECONDS
- Cannot connect to the remote server

[Problems]
 - Unexpected error: null

Comment: Seems there is some issue with your settings. This has nothing to do with procedure mentioned in blog. Search for this error and you will find many articles, may be those can help you with settings.

Comment: @GirijaS you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found [Locust](http://locust.io/) very useful and easy to use for load testing. Check it out.